# Codeigniter transaction not catching errors

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter transactions for mysql. My code is

```
public function create_user($user_data, $customer_data, $company_data)
{

    $this->db->trans_begin(); # Starting Transaction
    # See Note 01. If you wish can remove as well 

    $res_id=$this->db->insert_id('customers', $customer_data); # Inserting data
    error_log('RES-id');
    error_log(strval($res_id));
    $user_data['resource_id']=$res_id;
    $this->db->insert('users', $user_data);

    # Updating data
    // $this->db->where('id', $id);
    // $this->db->update('table_name', $test); 




    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        # Something went wrong.
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else {
        # Everything is Perfect. 
        # Committing data to the database.
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

I am error_logging some things for debugging purpose. So I am doing transactions to first fetch the id which is auto-incremental and then that id has to be inserted into users table. But its returning 0 and not throwing any error. I need help in it.

Comment: You should get the last inserted id after insertion complete.

    $res_id=$this->db->insert('customers', $customer_data); # Inserting data
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    error_log('RES-id');
    error_log(strval($insert_id));
    $user_data['resource_id']=$insert_id;
    $this->db->insert('users', $user_data);

Comment: If any insertion deletion fails because of wrong table name or column name will it be catched by trans_status===FALSE()

Comment: make sure you have persmissions to write in `application/logs` folder